# How to show multiple echos on the same line without -ne?

Tags: linux, shell, echo

I want to show multiple Echos on one line. My problem is. -ne won't work.
My Code is right now:

```
echo -ne "Not enough Space! Please free " >&2
echo "scale=2; $((reqSpace - availSpace)) /1024^2" | bc
echo " more GB"
```

Output is:

```
Not enough Space available! Please free 5
 more GB
```

When I put an -ne in the second lane my output is:

```
Not enough Space! Please free (standard_in) 1: syntax error
 more GB
```

How can I bring all these echos on one line? or how can I solve it different?
Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo -n` has undefined behavior, whereas `echo -e` is defined in a way that requires `echo` to print `-e` on output -- which is to say, you're depending on your shell behaving in a way that defies the standard.

Comment: See [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue you have here is that `bc` always emits output as a UNIX text stream -- meaning always with newline delimiters on the end.

Using a command substitution to capture the output from `bc` implicitly strips the trailing newline, thus resolving this.

---

Your command substitution can simply be substituted directly into the `echo` command:

```
echo "Not enough Space! Please free $(bc <<<"scale=2; $((reqSpace - availSpace)) /1024^2") more GB" >&2
```

You might also consider using `printf` instead:

```
printf 'Not enough space! Please free %s more GB\n' \
  "$(bc <<<"scale=2; $((reqSpace - availSpace)) /1024^2")" >&2
```

That said, you *could* also strip that newline from `bc`'s output, as done here with `tr`:

```
printf "Not enough Space! Please free " >&2
echo "scale=2; $((reqSpace - availSpace)) /1024^2" | bc | tr -d '\n' >&2
echo " more GB"
```